# What do the browser performance acronyms "HRBR" "TTFCP" & "RTT" mean?

Tags: seo, performance, browsers, load-time

They're used in this article on resource hints:  https://medium.com/reloading/a-link-rel-preload-analysis-from-the-chrome-data-saver-team-5edf54b08715

I can't find then used anywhere else though, nor any definition of their meaning.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague found the answers as soon as I finished posting:

RTT := **R**ound **T**rip **T**ime

TTFCP := **T**ime **T**o **F**irst **C**ontent **P**aint

HRBR := **H**idden **R**ender **B**locking **R**esource